# Why browser doesn't see this CSS property

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some element, which is added via Jquery:

```
$('body').delegate('.tutorial_links', 'click', function(){
        var $tutorial_hider="<a href='#' class='hider_tutorial' data-method='delete' data-remote='true' rel='nofollow' style='display:inline-block; background-color:#68d574;  width:"
        $width=$(this).parent().width()
        $tutorial_hider=$tutorial_hider+$width+"px'></a>"
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $(this).before($($tutorial_hider));
    })
```

Which has relative CSS:

```
.hider_tutorial{
    height: 15px;
    vertical-align: -1px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0;
}

.hider_tutorial:hover{
 background-color: rgba(214, 19, 84, 0.70);
}
```

And if just CSS for `hider_tutorial` works, browser just doesn't see  `.hider_tutorial:hover` (when I inspect element in Chrome or Firefox, there is just nothing about `.hider_tutorial:hover`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inline style takes precedence over all other CSS rules. That is, the `background-color:#68d574` property defined in the `style` attribute has a higher priority than the properties in `.hider_tutorial` or `.hider_tutorial:hover`. [Check out this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/KEuEX/) and hover both links. The first link changes background color as expected, while the second link always has its overridden color.

There are some ways to get around this:

- Use a class instead of manually applying styles. This ensures that "normal" precedence rules apply (as there are no inline styles taking priority) and it makes for cleaner code (all your styling is contained in the CSS file, instead of being scattered throughout the CSS and JavaScript code).
- Make the `background-color` property in `.hider_tutorial:hover` important with `!important`. This is more of a dirty fix in my book, as `!important` may sooner or later backfire when you find yourself in need to override an `!important` property.

Comment: thanks! it is funny, not long ago I was looking through css source of one site i like, and wondering, why !important needed)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open developer console
2. Click in the element
3. Click in the arrow dot bordered in the right side panel -> Toggle element state

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZMGv.jpg

Comment: I don't understand your comment, I'm not a native english

Comment: @JoeHalfFace This has nothing to do with "cash" (cache?)